# How to pass all lines of a file through a pipe?

Tags: c, pipe, ipc, readfile

I am trying to learn the communication of processes in C.

I would like to read all the lines of a file through a child process and pass them to the parent through a pipe. The father will have to print on the screen only the lines containing the word contained in the "word" variable

Can you tell me if this solution is correct?

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
     if(argc!=3)
    {
        perror(">>Error");
        exit(1);
    }
    FILE *file;
    const char* filename= argv[2];
    const char* word=argv[1];

    int pipefd[2];

    if (pipe(pipefd) == -1) {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(1);
    }

    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

    if(fork()==0)//child R
    {
        if((file=fopen(filename,"r"))==NULL)
        {
            perror("fopen");
            exit(1);
        }

        close(pipefd[0]);
        while(fgets(buffer,BUFFER_SIZE,file)!=NULL)
        {
            if((write(pipefd[1],buffer,sizeof(buffer)))==-1)
            {
                perror("Error write pipe");
                exit(1);
            }

        }
        fclose(file);
        close(pipefd[1]);
        exit(0);

    }
    else //father P
    {   
        
        sleep(1);
        close(pipefd[1]);
         

        while((read(pipefd[0],buffer,sizeof(buffer))>0)){

                if(strstr(buffer,word)!=NULL)
                printf("buffer: %s", buffer);
        }

        close(pipefd[0]);
        exit(0);

    }
}
```

Comment: I seems to be missing some header file inclusions. Is that the problem? Please share the error message - or whatever it is that made you ask the question.

Comment: `if((write(pipefd[1],buffer,sizeof(buffer)))==-1)` You should take a closer look at spec for `fgets`. It will stop reading when an `\n` is seen.

Comment: "Can you tell me if this solution is correct? What happened when you tested it? Did it (seem to) work?

Comment: `if(strstr(buffer,word)!=NULL)` That function expects to get strings. Where do you ensure that `buffer` is a string?

Comment: The program works. I would just like to understand if the implementation is correct

Comment: OK. It seemed to work by accident. You need to fix the errors I pointed out above.

Comment: I have no idea how to correct what you just told me. I was trying, but I can't

Comment: The first one is easy: Instead of `sizeof(buffer)` use `strlen(buffer)` to only write what you have actually read from the file.

Comment: do I have to change it both to the reading you write?
The output is a little weird now

Comment: I chage`if((write(pipefd[1],buffer,sizeof(buffer)))==-1)` to `if((write(pipefd[1],buffer,strlen(buffer)))==-1)` but the output is weird.

Comment: Output:                                                                                                                           
`buffer: House 
Hello
Car
Moto
House
Mouse
City
Alex
PC
Hello
Hello????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????ڰ?% `.

Comment: Why this:  ´????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????ڰ?%´

Comment: Because that is second issue: `buffer` is not a string. You never add nul-termination after reading data. You must store result of `read` and place a `0` at the corresponding position in the buffer. That also means your buffer must be only byte larger than the size you use for `read`.

Comment: That "only one byte" above should be "at least 1 byte"

Comment: I still can't understand! Could you give me an example with some code?